# Is there a way to use the which argument in for loop in R?

Tags: r, loops

I'm trying to write a for loop to find the highest 100 (as an example) variables in each index and reassign them all the 100th highest value. The for loop is starting at the max for the index and testing to see if the number of cases matching the max value exceeds the threshold. If less than 100 cases match the maximum, the maximum variable is reduced by 1 and run again.  If 100 or more cases match, the max is adjusted back to the previous value and the cases are assigned that value.

I'm trying to actually use this on a data set to adjust the values for top and bottom 0.075% to a new max and min respectively without crossing over the 0.75% threshold. My actual data has over 400k cases and 170 features that I'm trying use this on.

I don't need to fix this if there is a better way to do what I described above.

df should have: a = values from 0-100 and 101 for 100 cases, b = values from 100-200 and 201 for 100 cases, c = values from 200-300 and 301 for 100 cases.

I tried to use the length(which(df[i]) in the if and else statements and thought that assigning it to a variable might help but it didn't.

```r
a=c(0:200) 
b=c(100:300)
c=c(200:400)
df <- data.frame(a, b, c)  

for (i in 1:length(df)){
  max_count <- length(which(df[i]))
  maximum <-max(df[i])
  if (((max_count > maximum) < 100) == FALSE){
    maximum <- maximum -1
  }
  else if (((max_count > maximum) >= 100) == TRUE){
    df[i](which(df[i] > maximum +1)) <- maximum +1
  }
}

>>> Error in which(df[i]) : argument to 'which' is not logical
```

Comment: What would be your expected output for the `df` shared?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish in the statement `max_count <- length(which(df[i]))` ?

Comment: I tried to use the length(which(df[i]) in the if and else statements and thought that assigning it to a variable might help resolve the error but it didn't.

Comment: I'd strongly encourage you to use `df[[i]]` or `df[, i]` to extract a column. `df[i]` is a one-column data frame, and I have no idea what `which(df[i])` is supposed to do. I'm pretty confused about your overall goal too, which makes it hard to help. Could you, as Ronak asks, show the output you are looking for? Maybe use a smaller example with only 10 rows and a 5 maximum count to illustrate clearly?